# How do you move all files from the previous directory to the pwd?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

If I enter

```
cd -
```

in the command line, I go to previous location I was at. I want to do something like (obviously the below line doesn't actually work):

```
mv -/* .
```

To copy everything from the previous directory to where I currently am, without having to explicitly type out the entire previous directory. Is this possible? (On Ubuntu 16.04?, using bash)

Comment: "pwd" means password and does not make sense in the rest of the context of your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### How do I refer to the previous directory I was in on the command line of in a script?

A couple of different ways:

- Use the `$OLDPWD` variable

  Source: [Bash - $OLDPWD | bash Tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/bash/example/16875/-oldpwd)
- To use the `-` shortcut prefix it with a `~`

  `~-`

  > **Tilde Expansion**
  >
  > If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character ('~'), all of the characters up to the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if
  >   there is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix. If none of
  >   the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the
  >   tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible login name.
  >   If this login name is the null string, the tilde is replaced with the
  >   value of the HOME shell variable. If HOME is unset, the home directory
  >   of the user executing the shell is substituted instead. Otherwise, the
  >   tilde-prefix is replaced with the home directory associated with the
  >   specified login name.
  >
  > If the tilde-prefix is '~+', the value of the shell variable PWD replaces the tilde-prefix. If the tilde-prefix is '~-', the value of
  >   the shell variable OLDPWD, if it is set, is substituted.

  Source: [How-To: shell expansion - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-expand.html)

Examples:

```
$ ls
bin  sh.exe.stackdump  test  test.txt
$ cd test
$ ls
test.sh
$ ls $OLDPWD
bin  sh.exe.stackdump  test  test.txt
$ ls ~-
bin  sh.exe.stackdump  test  test.txt
$
```